# How to solve the problem of NDK library calls freezing UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk

I have a C library which I access through NDK. Some operations are time consuming so UI thread freezes on them. As I now the common practice is to use Runnable like that:

```
myFixedThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
    NativeClass.callToNDKLibrary();
  };
});
```

or threads like that:

```
Thread t = new Thread() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
    NativeClass.callToNDKLibrary();
  }
};
t.start();
```

but the problem is that C library is not thread safe: it starts to crash when I wrap it like this. So the question is how to detach from UI thread still enforcing NDK calls to run one at a time. May be some trick with synchronized will help? I also want to mention that this library is a core underlying layer for my application, not just a helper function. So it's called from nearly every part of my code. And only a few functions consume time, most a quick to keep them in main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution is as follows:

1. Define all JNI native methods as synchronized. This will prevent C library from crashing but still will freeze UI.
2. Define single thread executor:

   ExecutorService mExecutorThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
3. Wrap all time consuming operations in that thread:

   mExecutorThread.execute(new Runnable() 
   {
     public void run() 
     {
       NativeClass.callToNDKLibrary();
     }
   });

Last thing I had to do was to slightly redesign my code to make sure that none of native methods are called from onDraw(). I made the results of native methods cached in event handlers and used that cached values in onDraw().

Answer (score 2):

> but the problem is that C library is not thread safe: it starts to crash when I wrap it like this.

Then use a single dedicated background thread for all operations on the library. For example, use an `IntentService` to access the library, with the activities calling startService() to send commands to the `IntentService`.

Or:

1. Create a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Job>`, for some `Job` class/interface you define
2. Have a single thread monitor that queue
3. Send jobs to that queue to access your library
4. Send a special "kill job" to the queue to cause the monitor-the-queue loop to exit, causing the background thread to terminate, once you no longer need the queue and thread

Or, spend the time to make the library thread-safe at the C level. Making C code be thread-safe has been a topic of discussion for ~20 years, so there is probably some tricks you can use that have arisen from all that experience.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me a clue where to start thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Looper.html) to create a message loop.  Then pass your NDK calls in via a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and each will be run in turn.